# Nested json to Hive table

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

My json file looks like:

```
{VALUES:[{"UTAGID":"SYSTEM_CHILLER1","tagName":"P1","tagValue":"10","tagTime":"2015-07-23T14:29:30.731Z","tagQuality":"128"}'
...........}]};
```

I wrote the json schema as:

```
create table t1(VALUES array<<struct<UTAGID:STRING, tagName:STRING, tagValue:STRING, tagTime:STRING, tagQuality:STRING>>)

ROW FORMAT SERDE "org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde"

STORED AS TEXTFILE;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH"/tmp/jsonstreaming.json"into table t1;
```

But i'm still getting the error as ParseException missing < near struct keyword.
what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra `<` try

```
create table t1(VALUES array<struct<UTAGID:STRING, tagName:STRING, tagValue:STRING, tagTime:STRING, tagQuality:STRING>>)
```

Comment: sorry..i did type it in the same way you have mentioned but still got the same error..